# I'm looking for Python and Golang benchmarks for processing speed in Google Cloud Dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

Golang is much faster than  Python.

However, in the case of Google Cloud Dataflow where Apache Beam is used as a programming model,
I want to understand whether the processing speed difference between Python and Golang is nearly the same or Golang is much faster than Python.

So I'm looking for Golang and Python benchmark material with big data in **Dataflow.**

Furthermore, it is even better to indicate the cause of the speed difference.

Comment: I don't believe Go SDK is officially supported for Dataflow yet.

Comment: hello chamikara, thanks for your quickly reply.
I decide to use Python SDK.

Answer (score 1):

While Go as a language has advantages over Python, python benefits from tight interoperation with C, which gives it some speed benefits, since many of the more popular libraries have C implementations. Python is highly favoured for Machine Learning as a result, including for Beam.

Do you have any particular usecases that you would find valuable as comparisons?

The current expectation is that Go workers will have improved startup time compared to Python workers, but beyond that, it's harder to say without a concrete scenario.

---

I work on the Beam Go SDK. Currently the SDK isn't supported on Dataflow, and there are no comparative benchmarks between the Go and Python SDKs at present.

The Go SDK is still considered experimental. See [the roadmap](https://beam.apache.org/roadmap/go-sdk/) for the blockers in resolving that, which are currently in progress.

Comment: hello Robert Burke, thanks for your effective reply.
I decide to use Python SDK.